# Question re: Recent full service restaurant data sweep (W&H Compliance)

Tags: labor, restaurant

I am working with the Wage & Hour Compliance Data to understand FLSA violations in the full-service restaurant sector and am using the WHD Whisard dataset. I am wondering if there has been a recent data sweep for full-service restaurant wage violations? My specific area of interest is in the sub-minimum wage (aka tipped wage).

A secondary question is: is there a variable for repeat offenders?

Thank you!